# Cucumber - variable in Scenario title without using it in the body

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, scenarios

In Cucumber, I want to use variables in the title without using it in the body.
For example:

```
 Scenario Outline: Test case described at <excel_line>
    Given the following devices
      | name    | type     |
      | device  | <device> |
    When a <device> is active
    Then I get a message
    Examples:
    | device  | excel_line  |
    | Android | 1           |
    | IPhone  | 2           |
```

As you can see <excel_line> varies in title only, never should be used in body.

Is that possible?

Comment: I've seen people do this with SpecFlow, a Gherkin implementation for the .NET framework. I'm curious about Cucumber. Can you try this out? Then [edit] your question to include the error message.

Comment: What about putting the excel_line column first in the examples table? Maybe the test runner will name the test cases after the value in the first column for each row?

Comment: I actually don't about SpecFlow.

Comment: There is no error message, just the title doesn't appear withe the variable, but as v.g. "Test case described at <excel_line>"

Comment: The order in the Examples table doesn't matter

Comment: Which programming language are you working in? Judging by your answer, is it Ruby?

Comment: That is right, Ruby

Answer (score 0):

I could find in a project I am a workaround that I'm happy with.
The variable is used in the body, but it at least doesn't seem so.

Do a step like the following (in case of Ruby)

```
Given('Scenario title: {string}') do |scenario_title|
  puts "scenario_title : #{scenario_title}"
end
```

And then:

```
 Scenario Outline:
    * Scenario title: Test case described at <excel_line>
    Given the following devices
      | name    | type     |
      | device  | <device> |
    When a <device> is active
    Then I get a message
    Examples:
    | device  | excel_line  |
    | Android | 1           |
    | IPhone  | 2           |
```